# MEF Plugins with Security and Profiles Efficency

Tags: c#, wpf, mef

I have an application that has many modules/plugins.  I am using MEF with a Directory plugin to import them.  Each user has a list of available modules stored in a database and each user can have multiple profiles controlling which modules are visible.

There is an overview area showing information from all visible modules with an [ImportMany(typeof(IModule)]  attribute.

What is a good way of handling this so that invisible or inaccessible modules are not created in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lazy loading them](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lazy%20Exports&referringTitle=Guide) will ensure they are not initialised or loaded into memory. Then [use metadata](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exports%20and%20Metadata&referringTitle=Guide) to find the module names and details.

Answer (score -1):

Using `[ImportMany(typeof(IModule)]` will create an instance of each module - that's just the way MEF works. So one approach would be for the constructors of your Modules to do nothing, and then call a `Load` method on each Module that you actually want to use, in which it can do whatever work it needs to do.

Alternatively, create a new interface called `IModuleInfo` which just has the information necessary for your overview area.